# Monotouch Dialog Json, EntryElement use EntryEnded Event

Tags: json, events, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to use MTD with Json to dinamycally create forms, but also i need to check the user input:

Some fields may only accept numbers, and some other have a fixed length etc.
This can be done with an action that checks every EntryElement value against the specified conditions, and then using some messaging to tell the user about the necessary corrections.

If we have a low number of fields this is Ok, but when one has more than 50 fields then this turn out to be very awkward in terms of usability. The ideal solution would be to notify the user about corrections, in the moment the user ends typing in the EntryElement

Now MTD provides some sort of mechanism to do this:

```
JsonElement jsonElement;
jsonElement = JsonObject.Load("file.json");
((EntryElement) jsonElement["field_1"]).EntryEnded = delegate { doSomething();};
```

Provided that "field_1" is an EntryElement marked with the id attribute with "field_1" value
The above code works as expected, ie: When i change the focus to another part, the EntryEnded event activates. Now for the million dollar question:

How do i know to which EntryElement does the Event correspond? or in other words.
 How do i get the ID of the EntryElement when calling the Event?

If none of the above is possible which would be suitable solution?

Thanks in advance for any leads,

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it:

```
((EntryElement)jsonElement ["field_1"]).EntryEnded += (object sender, EventArgs e ) =>
{
  NSIndexPath pt = ((EntryElement)sender).IndexPath;
  Console.WriteLine("section: "+pt.Section+" row: "+pt.Row);
};
```

This little thing will print the Section and the Row of the EntryElement that received
the EntryEnded event. This is not exactly as getting the id, but at least now i have information about its location, and from this i can get a lot more info (specially if i took care to save it somewhere else)

This is probably a basic trick, but i didn`t found it anywhere else!